# Update body style in mobx store reaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a modal component (React) that observes changes with open, close method in mobx store.

When open, I need to set `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` to preserve modal scroll. In close, I clear the hidden style from the body.

```
@action open = () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
}

@action close = () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = ''
}
```

Is there a better way to do this with `autorun`?

I can't figure out where to invoke autorun, outside the Store Class or has a method inside. I had no luck.

```
autorun(
  () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = this.isMaximized ? 'hidden' : ''
  },
  { name: 'bodyOverflowUpdate' }
)
```

For reference, `this.isMaximized` is a computed value

```
@computed
  get isMaximized() {
    return this.modalState.isOpen && !this.modalState.isMinimized
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a mobx reaction seems so solve my use case

```
setBodyOverflow = reaction(
    () => this.isMaximized,
    isMaximized => {
      document.body.style.overflow = isMaximized ? 'hidden' : ''
    },
    { name: 'setBodyOverflow' },
  )
```